# Magento 2.3 customer beforeAuthenticate plugin not working

Tags: customer, logging, before-plugin, authentication

I am facing **allowed memory size of bytes exhausted** when ever trying to login customer in magento 2.3.2

I have used **beforeAuthenticate** plugin to do some functionality after sometime customer can not logging In. i have disabled my custom extension but still facing same issue.

**File 1. Demo\Common\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement">
    <plugin name="xxx_set_password_if_empty" type="Demo\Common\Plugin\Customer\Model\AccountManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
```

**File 2 Demo\Common\Plugin\Customer\Model\AccountManagement.php**

```
namespace Demo\Common\Plugin\Customer\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface as Encryptor;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class AccountManagement
{
private $customerRegistry;
private $customerRepository;
private $encryptor;
private $connection;

public function __construct(
    CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
    Encryptor $encryptor,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository

) {
    $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
    $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}
public function beforeAuthenticate(\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $subject, $username, $password)
{

    try {
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($username);
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
    }

    /* START : Logic to set customer's password if found empty within our database */
    $customerSecure = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId());

    try {
        if(empty($customerSecure->getData('password_hash'))) {

        }
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return array($username, $password);
        }
    return array($username, $password);
    /* END : Logic to set customer's password if found empty within our database */
}

}
```

Comment: When you're getting this error at the time of compilation?

Comment: when customer trying to loggin

Comment: Can you please update your Plugin code here with di.xml file content ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase memory size, there are 3 ways to increase memory size:

1. Index.php: (ini_set("memory_limit","-1");
2. php.ini:   (memory_limit = 512M);
3. .htaccess: (php_value memory_limit 512M);

You can find these links useful:
[php memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

[Magneto 2 memory error](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Allowed-memory-size-of-2097152-bytes-exhausted/td-p/134267)